# How to get order of posts?

Tags: wp-query, loop, order, sort

How can I get the order through which the query is done?

For example, my woocommerce product archive page is querying by ordering according to the order_by select box (as seen below).

How can I get what my posts are ordered by?

For example, if it's default sorting, I want to know. If it's by popularity, I want to know. If it's by newness, I want to know.

[image]

Comment: The down/close votes are probably from members who are doing this by default the moment they see the word _WooCommerce_. :(   However, your question applies to any post type, it is interesting and on-topic. Good to see that you solved it already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer from the WordPress docs.

For what the query is ordered by, I use:

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->get('orderby');
```

For the order by which the posts are queried:

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->get('order');
```

Comment: @cybmeta Yeah, but I have to wait for two days. I will.

Comment: 2 days have passed. You can mark it now :)